# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'then' was called on null

Tags: flutter

Here is where I believe the error is located

```
void initState() {
    crudMethods.getData().then((result) {
      blogSnapshot = result;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Here is the exact error I get in the simulator
[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVHB0.png)

Comment: Maybe you can write; crudMethods.getData()?.then(...)

The "?" sign before then will handle null for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `getData` method returns `null`. Use `null safe` call:

```
void initState() {
    crudMethods.getData()?.then((result) {
      blogSnapshot = result;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

This will call `then` only if `getData()` returns some value